# Google Font looks bolder in Mac browsers

Tags: macos, fonts

Google Font looks bolder in Mac browsers than any other browsers of windows OS.

Comment: Which font? Have you checked that the same font is actually used by the browser?

Comment: I used roboto from google. pls find the link.
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400italic,400,500,700italic,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

Comment: And have you checked that the browser is actually using that font?

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution that is, I have used the -webkit-font-smoothing css property with antialised value. It has fixed.

Thanks for your answers.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is also the retina display of Apple?